# Nvim not getting correct terminal size opening session in tmux

Tags: neovim, macos, tmux

MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 + iTerm2, build 3.1.4 + NeoVim 0.2.0_1.
I run on iTerm a Tmux session loaded with

```
teamocil [session]
```

In one of tmux windows there's an instance of nvim working smoothly, everything is displayed in its own place in all of the bottom three lines, from last one: tmux status bar, nvim command line, nvim status line.
Here's the relevant shot:

[image: Everything in place]

In another tmux window I want to use a nvim session, sourced with

```
nvim -S [path to session.vim]
```

But here, in this nvim restored session, Tmux does not allow nvim to display messages in its command line, leaving no free lines between Tmux and nvim status lines. Whatever message displayed ovelaps status line, getting an unreadable mess. See following shot:

[image: nvim session mess]

It looks like nvim is not getting the correct terminal size when it starts session, either it is not reading it correctly or it is missing the WINCH signal.
Sending a

```
kill -WINCH $PID
```

signal from another shell solves the problem, so I adopted this as a temporary workaround, sending above command as a slightly delayed background process when opening tmux session.
But I think this is a neovim related issue and has to be fixed.

Just to make it clear the problem appears only sourcing an existing nvim session inside Tmux.
Thank you.

Comment: The problem spontaneously solved updating some homebrew formulae and/or restarting for the n.th time iTerm2.
This may be closed.
Thank you.